# Can you "slide your finger across a word"?

Tags: verbs, adverbs

How would you explain users of a mobile game how to use this feature ?

I have a few ideas but I fear they might not sound natural to native English speakers:

- "Display the definition of any word by *swiping over it.*"
- "Display the definition of any word by *sliding your finger across/over it*."

The velocity of the "slide" gesture is not important, so I believe using the *swipe* verb is not appropriate.

What would be the best way to phrase this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since "swipe" is the established idiom and is briefer than the alternative (which, in addition, doesn't sound immediately English - it is gramatically correct, but the wording isn't habitual, it's not a recognizable idiom), I recommend going with "swiping over it".

Comment: Yet I found usage of *slide across* in what I believe is a reliable source: ["On the keyboard, slide your finger across the letters of the word you want."](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2811346?hl=en)

Comment: I might prefer *swipe across* rather than swipe over... although I'm not sure why!